# How to execute Python code from Javascript for dummies

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I'm looking for an answer to this question that frames the issue for someone who doesn't really understand http requests and is attempting this for the first time.

I wanted to make a simple html web application for running an online experiment. Right now we don't have a server and we're just trying to make a prototype that functions on a local machine offline. I'm using a javascript framework for behavioral experiments that makes things easier, but I have this block of code indicating that want a python script called "create_stimuli.py" to execute its main function upon finishing the trial. I was hoping to pass one parameter collected from a form, the number of trials, to this python script.

```
    var creating_stimuli = {
    type: "html-keyboard-response",
    stimulus: "<p>Stimuli for this trial will be initialized upon continuing and experiment session with user will begin</p>" + 
            "<p>Closing the tab or window for this experiment will result in data loss. Reaction times will be measured</p>",
    prompt: "press any key to continue",
    on_finish: function(data){
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Scripts/create_stimuli.py",
            type: "POST",
            //I do need to pass in a parameter
            success: function(response) {
                //manipulate response variable here
            }
        })
    }
}
```

My python file doesn't have any special conventions at the moment, it's just like a regular python program - it just has some import statements at the top. I'm not sure if I need something else.

The error message I get for executing this javascript is the following.
jquery.min.js:2 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'file:///D:/Scripts/create_stimuli.py' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.

I genuinely don't quite understand what this error message means, though I can at least take the hint that I wasn't using protocol schemes correctly at all. And I'm not sure how to edit my javascript code to get it in the right direction.

From google searching, I find approaches that use Flask, AJAX, XMLHttpRequests, CGI and other approaches... Other than the fact that I need AJAX, I can't tell which tools I actually need to accomplish. Do I really need a whole web development framework like Flask just to execute a python script from Javascript?

Comment: The point is that JS in the browser doesn't have the ability to run a script on your own machine; think of the security implications if any random website could do that. So do need to have some kind of client/server setup, even if the client and server are the same machine, and communicate via Ajax. Flask is pretty easy to get started with, you should take a look at the tutorial.

Comment: Okay, got it. i needed that clarified. JS isn't meant to run scripts directly on a client's machine for security purposes, it seems. So I need to use Flask, create the python script on the Flask server, call that via Javascript (probably with AJAX) so that the python script can be executed on the server and the data can be transferred to the client as needed.

Comment: Yes. As I say though, if you're just planning to run this on a local machine for demonstration purposes the Flask server can live on the same machine, so your Ajax URL would be pointing at localhost.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you do it. This will give a quickstart for anyone intending to do behavioral experiments in JsPsych. The following code will allow you to pass in js variables using an AJAX call from Javascript to a python script. This logs a variable for number of trials in the console. if calling the script fails, an alert box is shown instead.

These links are helpful, particularly becasue the first talks about the potential importance of using an `__init__.py` script and organizing flask in a more modular way like how flask  documentation actually does
https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-xv-a-better-application-structure

It is best to create a simple `__init__.py` that can reliably boot/work without bugs. Your `__init__.py` program probably need to be able to be able to handle the url request of "/", the home page for your app. `__init__.py` also needs to register the blueprint variable created for whatever python program you intend to execute "remotely" from javascript/via AJAX. In that Here's what that `__init__.py` function might look like.

```
    import os
    from flask import Flask
    from flask import (
        Blueprint, flash, g, redirect, render_template, request, session, url_for
    )

    def create_app(test_config=None):
    # create and configure the app
    app = Flask(__name__, instance_relative_config=True) # creates the flask instance
    app.config.from_mapping(
        SECRET_KEY='dev',
    )

    if test_config is None:
        # load the instance config, if it exists, when not testing
        app.config.from_pyfile('config.py', silent=True)
    else:
        # load the test config if passed in
        app.config.from_mapping(test_config)

    # ensure the instance folder exists
    try:
        os.makedirs(app.instance_path)
    except OSError:
        pass
    from . import experiment // from '.' or this current directory, import the python program/module entitled "experiment.py"
    app.register_blueprint(experiment.bp) // register the blueprint variable created in experiment.py 

    app.add_url_rule('/', endpoint='index') //requests the url associated with '/'



    return app
```

I created a python program called experiment.py, it lives in the same directory as `__init__.py`. Both of these scripts are at the topmost level of this flask application directory structure, I'm following the structure in the blog post I included (and again, what's in Flask documentation)
`experiment.py` servers the same purpose as `app.py`, which is what people used to commonly refer to scripts containing view functions/python code to execute (if I got the terminology right)

Anyways, experiment.py needs to use `blueprint.route('/url_path')` to mount python "view functions" to particular urls that can be requested. You also need to return "render_template('index.html')" to return the html for the homepage (but you technically can return anything else.

This is what `experiment.py` looks like

```
        import functools

from flask import (
    Blueprint, flash, g, redirect, render_template, request, session, url_for
)
from werkzeug.security import check_password_hash, generate_password_hash

    bp= Blueprint('experiment', __name__)

    @bp.route('/')
    def index():
        return render_template("index.html")


    @bp.route('/testing', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def testing_func():
       trial_num = request.form['trials']
    return trial_num
```

In your jS script, if you just use an AJAX script containing a dictionary/JSON dictionary, it gets embedded into a flask request object in the "form" parameter as form data. You can access data parameterized in a field, "data" (that lives in the AJAX script) in python using request.form['key_name']

For JS (and if you're using the jspsych framework, the AJAX request might look like.

```
    var creating_stimuli = {
        type: "html-keyboard-response",
        stimulus: "<p>Stimuli for this trial will be initialized upon continuing and experiment session with user will begin</p>" + 
                "<p>Closing the tab or window for this experiment will result in data loss. Reaction times will be measured</p>",
        prompt: "press any key to continue",
        on_finish: function(data){
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST", // declaring AJAX post request
        url: "/testing", //Needs to go to the url mounted
        data: {
          trials:100
        },
        success: function(response) {
          console.log(response);
        },
        error: function(xhr, textStatus, thrownError) {
          alert('err');
        }
      });
        }
    }

    timeline_arr.push(creating_stimuli);
```